# Can Gobby/Sobby be used for collaborative edition for a team of developers?

Tags: text-editor, collaborative

[Gobby/Sobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) is an open source client/server for collaborative edition of plain text file (source code).

My question is 4-fold :

- Can you share any real-life usage of Gobby/Sobby for development among a group of physically separated developers ?
- Is the project mature enough as a productivity tool ?
- What are the working use cases ?
- What versions should be used ? (It seems 'undo' feature is not yet officially packaged)

Thanks
Jerome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes
- Mostly, you encounter issues running Windows clients (random crashes).  Find a version that works and stick to it.
- I recently started using it with the team I manage.  It has definitely increased my productivity when reviewing code, implementation collaboration, and answering general questions.  It's great for those "hey, can you take a quick look a this?" questions.
- We have only used development release 0.4.93.